# Dreamweaver data source won't work after the first try on Mac OS X

Tags: sqldatasource, dreamweaver

I have a problem with the Adobe Dreamweaver CS5  version 11.
I am running Mac OS X Leopard.
One fine day I found out about Adobe Dreamweaver's quick (& dirty) automated back-end programming.
I defined a data source and it worked as advertised. I setup a lot of pages and it was all fuzzy and romantic.
Next day I found out that I can't define Record-sets any more. I even tried setting up new data sources but all I get is this message:
[image]

This error message is obviously a great help... but I still thought I would consult my friends at stackoverflow!!
cheers!
Marci

***Update #1***
*I just found out I get the same message even when I am trying to connect to a mysql database on the localhost!  (I have the latest MAMP installed on my Mac Pro)*

Comment: any help would be appreciated!

Comment: come on there's got to be someone out there who know this quirk of Dreamweaver!! :/